# Is there a name for a "search" box which does more than just search?

Tags: search, terminology

My team and I are developing a search box which will allow for more than just searching. The goal is to allow users to do not only complex queries, but also use the box for go-tos and some calculations. For example:

- new request (would go to the new request page)
- super nintendos (find all super nintendos)
- John Smith (search for people named John Smith)
- John Smith in building 3124 (people named John Smith in building 3124)
- property owned by John Smith in building 3124 (I think you get the idea)
- 138.96.58.0/24 (show the ips for the subnet for the mask)

Think Google's search but dumbed down and specific to a web application. Internally we are referring to it as omni search as it feels like something more than "advanced" search. Is there a name for this type of search? Are we following a particular design pattern without knowing its name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More generally, you may see this referred to as **semantic search**, which tries to establish the meaning of words in a query.

> Semantic search seeks to improve search accuracy by understanding searcher intent and the contextual meaning of terms as they appear in the searchable dataspace, whether on the Web or within a closed system, to generate more relevant results.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_search)

Answer (score 6):

It is usually referred to as "**unified search**", which is both a name and a general description for what it is.  The term is used by many companies, including Zoho and Linkedin.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Chrome and Firefox do something similar in what was once called the address bar. They now refer to it as the **omnibox** and **awesome bar**, respectively. Hopefully someone will confirm my memory on those terms.

Comment: Yeah we totally lifted the name from Chrome, but didn't know if Google had lifted it from somewhere else.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But it's not a particularly original name either. Just reasonable language awareness ;)

Answer (score 1):

They call it [Graph search](https://www.facebook.com/about/graphsearch) at Facebook

[image]

At Apples it goes by the name of [Unified Smart Search Field](http://www.apple.com/safari/#search)

---

For your concern, there is a [fine article](http://www.smh.com.au/technology/technology-news/google-searching-for-star-trek-destiny-20130415-2hucf.html) about search research at Google and their *secret goal* :-).

Comment: Graph Search is more of a Facebook specific term and not a generic one which could be / should be used in other circumstances.

Comment: That was just my two cents so say the vocable has yet to be found.